# global javascript function is not being called onchange event of a file selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function which I am calling from the onChange event of the file selection box.

```
function cropper(){}
```

When I am trying to call this function from the onchange event of the file selection it is not working. I am calling it like

```
<label>Upload Photo:</label>
<input type="file" id="image_file" name="picture1" onchange="cropper()"/><br>
```

if I change the definition of function to like below it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(#image_file).change(function(){
    });
});
```

Could anyone please help me how to achieve it using the first approach. Thanks in advance.

JSFiddle Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ashishtyagi10/M5sqK/

Comment: What are the locations of the pieces of code

Comment: all the javascript code is in a separate file.

Comment: Is `cropper()` definitely defined as global (not inside a document ready handler)? And if you're using jQuery anyway, why would you want to take a step backwards to using global functions with inline event attributes?

Comment: Why do you want to use the first approach so badly?

Comment: if needed I can post JSFiddle link

Comment: I'm betting you have it in a jsFiddle and it's set to run `onLoad` (the default setting), so the function isn't declared globally

Comment: @Ian the reason I wants the first approach because I wants to call this function on multiple files.

Comment: it is not yet in fiddle, I may have to create the fiddle and then I will post it. I am sure I have declared the function globally, I can post the whole code if you wants

Comment: @Ashish you can do this too `$('input[type=file]').change(cropper)`; so you can call the function on multiple file inputs...No need to bind for each id. Btw here is a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/KGxL7/

Comment: Are you using `this` in `cropper`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishtyagi10/M5sqK/

Comment: You have a syntax error in that code, also toy have you code to run `onLoad` which means its going to be wrapped in a function so functions in there are not going to have global scope.

Comment: what is the syntax error, I will try to make that correct. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Open Developer Tools, it should tell you what the syntax error is.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Your `cropper` function is missing a closing `}`. It is obvious when you click the "tidy" button on your jsfiddle.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M5sqK/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems here

1. There is a syntax error `cropper` is not properly closed. There is a missing `}` at the end of the function
2. jQuery UI is not enabled
3. Your code is within `load` handler which means the `cropper` is not a global method. You need to select no-wrap body

Try

```
var selectImgWidth, selectImgHeight, jcrop_api, boundx, boundy, isError = false;
function cropper() {
    var previewId = document.getElementById('load_img');
    var thumbId = document.getElementById('thumb');
    previewId.src = '';
    $('#image_div').hide();
    var flag = 0;

    // Get selected file parameters
    var selectedImg = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];

    //Check the select file is JPG,PNG or GIF image
    var regex = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png)$/i;
    if (!regex.test(selectedImg.type)) {
        $('.error').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').fadeIn(500);
        flag++;
        isError = true;
    }

    if (flag === 0) {
        isError = false;
        $('.error').hide(); //if file is correct then hide the error message


        // Preview the selected image with object of HTML5 FileReader class
        // Make the HTML5 FileReader Object
        var oReader = new FileReader();
        oReader.onload = function (e) {

            // e.target.result is the DataURL (temporary source of the image)
            thumbId.src = previewId.src = e.target.result;

            // FileReader onload event handler
            previewId.onload = function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open"); //--> this is where dialog box is opened
                // display the image with fading effect
                $('#image_div').fadeIn(500);
                selectImgWidth = previewId.naturalWidth; //set the global image width
                selectImgHeight = previewId.naturalHeight; //set the global image height

                // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the Jcrop API and image size

                // destroy Jcrop if it is already existed
                if (typeof jcrop_api !== 'undefined') jcrop_api.destroy();

                // initialize Jcrop Plugin on the selected image
                $('#load_img').Jcrop({
                    minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
                    // aspectRatio : 1, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
                    bgFade: true, // use fade effect
                    bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
                    onChange: showThumbnail,
                    onSelect: showThumbnail
                }, function () {

                    // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
                    var bounds = this.getBounds();
                    boundx = bounds[0];
                    boundy = bounds[1];

                    // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
                    jcrop_api = this;
                });
            };
        };

        // read selected file as DataURL
        oReader.readAsDataURL(selectedImg);
    }
}    

function showThumbnail(e) {
    var rx = 155 / e.w; //155 is the width of outer div of your profile pic
    var ry = 190 / e.h; //190 is the height of outer div of your profile pic
    $('#w').val(e.w);
    $('#h').val(e.h);
    $('#w1').val(e.w);
    $('#h1').val(e.h);
    $('#x1').val(e.x);
    $('#y1').val(e.y);
    $('#x2').val(e.x2);
    $('#y2').val(e.y2);
    $('#thumb').css({
        width: Math.round(rx * selectImgWidth) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * selectImgHeight) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * e.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * e.y) + 'px'
    });
}


function validateForm() {
    if ($('#image_file').val() === '') {
        $('.error').html('Please select an image').fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    } else if (isError) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        dialogClass: 'DynamicDialogStyle',
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: $(window).width()-20,
        height: $(window).height()-10,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: {
        "Uploads": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
                        "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
  });
});



function botype(a) {
    if (a.options[a.selectedIndex].value === '1') {
        document.getElementById('showme').style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('showme').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bg8JC/)